# Doctrine PHP associations symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, associations

What should I do? I need to stablish doctrine associations between printer, Toner,tape and ink. One printer could just use One of those {toner,tape, ink}.

but i'm not sure what's the best way to do it. I want to use the best practice as possible (OOP).

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you will need a cross reference / xref table? Is that your thinking?

Comment: Yes i thought in something similiar but i'm not quite sure how to do it. Should I implement an interface for that?

Comment: So, if `type_of_consumable_id` is an FK, how do you know what table? Seems you lack a context. `type_of_consumable_type` or something...

Comment: The diagram is just a Class diagram it's not a relational one... it's just for explanation purpose. I know it wouldn't work in that way

Comment: You did say many-to-many right? I expect you want to remove `type_of_consumable_id` from the printer table. And then create a new 'XREF' table... say `PrinterConsumableXref`. That table would have one or more rows corresponding to a printer... With columns, `printer_id`, `type_of_consumable_type_id`, `type_of_consumable_id`... Think of that table as mapping btw. the two. Alternately flatten those three tables; toner, tape, ink, into one.

Comment: I've considered doing like that but i'm sure there's a better way. because if I do table reference by attribute I'll have to make hardcoding

Comment: Take a look at Doctrine's table inheritance capability.  You could have a consumable base class with ink,toner,tape children.

Comment: Yes, referential integrity is like that. You would probably add a table of `consumable_types`. But not like adding a new table is any easier, rather add a new row. I know my relational databases and have seen every conceivable way to accomplish this.

Comment: FYI: http://phpcrossref.com/xref/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/docs/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.rst.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine2 supports [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) – you can use it:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Printer
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Consumable")
     */
    private $consumable;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"toner" = "Toner", "ink" = "Ink"})
 */
abstract class Consumable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
final class Toner extends Consumable
{}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
final class Ink extends Consumable
{}
```